# Problema con conexion mysql en java

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo este código para conectarme a una bd pero el problema es que no entra al bucle while

```
public static void conf(){
    System.out.println("Ingrese serial");
    String numSerial = sc.nextLine();
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/seriales","root","");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT usado FROM serial WHERE serial = ?");
        ps.setString(1, numSerial);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            if(rs.equals(0)){
                System.out.println("No usado");
            }else if(rs.equals(1)){
                System.out.println("Usado");
            }
        }
        con.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

}

Cual puede ser el fallo.

Comment: Tienes filas que cumplan `SELECT usado FROM serial WHERE serial = 1`?

Comment: En mi bd tengo la tabla serial de tres columnas id,serial y usado, lo que quiero es seleccionar el campo usado cuando el String introducido por el usuario sea igual al campo serial, lo que quiero hacer seria SELECT usado FROM serial WHERE serial = numSerial, donde numSerial es el String introducido por el usuario.

Comment: @brunoDiazmartin Pregunta: ¿cuál es el tipo de la columna `serial`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero ¿El programa arroja alguna excepción? En tal caso, te recomiendo que, además de `System.out.println(ex);` agregues `ex.printStackTrace(System.out);` al bloque `catch`. Esto te permitirá identificar el lugar exacto donde se arroja la excepción.

Por otra parte, no estas recuperando ningún valor del `ResultSet`; para leer valores de un ResultSet debes usar alguno de los métodos `getXXX()`. Asumiendo que el valor de la columna `usado` es entero, puedes usar:

```java
if(rs.getInt(1) == 1) {  // También puede ser: rs.getInt("usado");
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

Recuerda: Cuando usas JDBC, las columnas de un `ResultSet` se numeran a partir de 1.

Ahora bien, para asegurarte de que el `ResultSet` tiene registros, sugiero las siguientes correcciones:

```java
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
                           "SELECT usado FROM serial WHERE serial = ?"
                           , ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE    // Esto asegura que el ResultSet pueda ser recorrido en cualquier dirección (adelante o atrás)
                           , ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY    // Esto asegura que el ResultSet sea de sólo lectura
                       );
ps.setString(1, numSerial);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
rs.beforeFirst();    // Coloca el cursor ANTES de la primera fila del ResultSet
                     // (para esto es que se requiere la opción TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE)
/* Si esperas que el ResultSet tenga una sola fila, puedes hacer esto: */
if(rs.first()) {
    if(rs.getInt("usado") == 1) {
        System.out.println("Usado");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No usado");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("No hay registros coincidentes");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El fallo creo que puede ser por 2 cosas:

1 - La consulta Select no te está devolviendo nada.

2 - La comparación que haces con equals `if(rs.equals(0))` puede que no haga lo que tú esperas.

Recuerda que equals solo te devuelve true si los dos objetos son del mismo tipo e iguales, por ejemplo:

```
if("1".equals(1)) -> FALSO

if("1".equals("1")) -> TRUE
```

Para hacer conversiones:

```
int numero = Integer.parseInt("1"); //Convierte un String en int
String texto = String.valueOf(2); //Convierte un int en String
```

Comment: Y como puedo saber si la consulta me devuelve algo, porque no creo que sea en el equals ya que la celda la tengo de tipo entero y en el if el cero o el 1 es un int no?