# Error, java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "conexion" is null

Tags: java, mysql-workbench

Estoy usando NeatBeans IDE 13 y estoy tratando de conectar a una base de datos (MySQL) como prueba, me logra conectar mediante un JOptionPane pero al querer mostrar el contenido de una tabla me sale ese error. Soy estudiante

public Connection getConnection(){
Connection conexion=null;

```
    try {
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,usuario,contraseña);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexion exitosa");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQLException: "+ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLSate: "+ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: "+ex.getErrorCode());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema con conexion mysql en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/17258/problema-con-conexion-mysql-en-java)

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate que tus variables URL usuario y contraseña sean correctas.
Es muy común que la variable de URL tenga algún caracter incorrecto y por ello no logre conectarse a tu DB, y por ello la variable conexion termina siendo nula.

Hay bastantes parámetros que puedes especificar dentro la URL

```
URL="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/{DBName}?"
        + "useSSL=false&"
        + "useTimezone=true&"
        + "serverTimezone=UTC&"
        + "allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true"
```

comparte tu archivo pom para poder ver las versiones de cada una de las dependencias que utilizas, así como tu compilador.

Comment: muchas gracias los import no me estaban funcionando en netbeans 13 lo sulucione pero esmucho lio con esta version